# What risks are involved upgrading communities templates

Tags: community

I read over the release notes for upgrading community templates and it indicates most component customizations and properties are overwritten for pre-Winter '16 templates. I'm running a test upgrade in a sandbox environment, but are there other risks to consider besides customizations being overwritten? Thanks.

Comment: Off hand, probably the biggest risk is that in NOT upgrading the templates you won't have support for the old ones in the future when it comes to editing, updating, etc beyond a certain point that's coming up fairly soon. I believe that was explained in the W16 release notes. As with everything, you'll need to test the changes you make in a Sandbox.

Comment: @crmprogdev Yep, we absolutely realize the upgrade is necessary and we'll lose support otherwise. I was concerned about any other risks than the customizations we might lose and have to fix. Based on the current testing, it isn't terrible, but again, double checking there are not other gotchas that I should be aware of that someone else might have encountered.

Comment: Most all of the "gotchas" that I've seen were release specific and long ago resolved. Those were primarily related to the Napoli Templates. I've not seen much of anything significant reported related to upgrading templates that's broken previous customizations that wouldn't be expected. Again, that's what sandbox testing is for.